# Child list for field Barcode cannot be created. vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

i don't know why my code does not work.

```
 Private Sub FillDataSetAndView()
    Ds = New DataSet
    Dim dt As New SqlDataAdapter("select [ID],[Onvan]'نام النگو ',[Tedad]'تعداد',[Vazn]'وزن ',[availability]'وضعیت' from BarcodeL where barcode=0 and Amar=1 and Type='طلا' ", connection)
    dt.Fill(Ds, "‌BarcodeL")
    objDataView = New DataView(Ds.Tables("BarcodeL"))
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "BarcodeL"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).Visible = False
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).Width = "200"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).Width = "100"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).Width = "100"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).Width = "120"
    '   DataGridView1.Columns.Item(6).Visible = False
End Sub
```

**gets me this error: Child list for field Barcode cannot be created.**

****But this code will work for another table. ****

Error Context:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Child list for field BarcodeL cannot be created.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.EnsureListManager(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.SetDataConnection(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_DataMember(String value)
   at Main.ListAlango.FillDataSetAndView() in C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\AYSA Jewelry\Main\ListAlango.vb:line 20
   at Main.ListAlango.ListAlango_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\AYSA Jewelry\Main\ListAlango.vb:line 12
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Don't create a `DataSet` in the first place. Just create a `DataTable`, `Fill` it and then assign it to the `DataSource`. If you were going to use a `DataSet` because you needed one, e.g. you had multiple `DataTables`, then you should set the `DataMember` first, before the `DataSource`.

Comment: By the way, this line appears to be useless: `objDataView = New DataView(Ds.Tables("BarcodeL"))`. What are you using that `DataView` for? Are you aware that every `DataTable` already has a `DataView` associated with in its `DefaultView` property and, when you bind a `DataTable`, that's where the data comes from?